# How to implement pivot_wider in sparklyr?

Tags: r, dplyr, sparklyr

I have a spark dataframe I want to transpose the dataframe longer to wider. using a `row` column

```
library(dplyr)
dummy <- data.frame("ID" = c(1,1,1,1,2,2),
                    "category"=c("A","A", "B", "B", "C", "C"),
                    "row"=c(1,2,1,2,1,2),
                    "quantity"=c(1,5,6,7,4,5),
                    "price"=c(10.2, 45.6, 70.3, 23.4, 10,11))

> dummy
   ID category row quantity price
 1  1        A   1        1  10.2
 2  1        A   2        5  45.6
 3  1        B   1        6  70.3
 4  1        B   2        7  23.4
 5  2        C   1        4  10.0
 6  2        C   2        5  11.0
```

i want to convert this into

```
dummy <-dummy %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(ID, category) %>% 
  tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = row, values_from = c(quantity, price))

> dummy

     ID category quantity_1 quantity_2 price_1 price_2
  <dbl> <fct>         <dbl>      <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
1     1 A                 1          5    10.2    45.6
2     1 B                 6          7    70.3    23.4
3     2 C                 4          5    10      11
```

but in sparklyr i'm not able to use pivot wide please suggest a solution

Comment: Can you try `sdf_pivot` i.e. `dummy %>% dplyr::group_by(ID, category)  %>% sdf_pivot(quantity + price ~ row)`

Comment: `> dummy %>% dplyr::group_by(ID, category) %>% sdf_pivot(quantity + price ~ row)`
`# Source: spark<?> [?? x 4]`
`  quantity price 1.0 2.0`
`1        4  10       1   NaN`
`2        1  10.2     1   NaN`
`3        5  11     NaN     1`
`4        5  45.6   NaN     1`
`5        7  23.4   NaN     1`
`6        6  70.3     1   NaN`
It generates the above table which is not the desired one

Comment: Because you may have to specify the `fun.aggregate` as `I`

Comment: I just want to transpose without aggregation

Comment: Yes, that is why I mentioned to use `I` which implies as is. Also, please check if there are duplicates and if so, create a sequence column